# Can Spark theoretically lose a data of the failed job?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

So we are using `RDD` and do a `flatMap` on a set of data. Then each element we are transforming with a map operation.

```scala
val elementsRDD: RDD[Element] = ...

val result = elements.map(processData);
```

On a fixed set of elements we see that on each run if some executors dies during a map operation the spark spin ups new executors but it doesn't provide a data to operation as a result we are loosing data. Our expectation that Spark should provide data or at least re-run stage from scratch.

We use a newest Kubernetes feature of Spark 2.4(which is still in development)

UPDATE: Documentation says that it's impossible situation, but our logging from executors shows that we lose different pieces of data during a data processing on a fixed set of data. Moreover that if we do not kill any executors during a process we do not lose any data.

Answer (score 3):

No. The data processed for the died executor will be lost, but when the driver notices the failure of an executor, it distributes the jobs of the death executor among the still alive executors. Spark won't successfully success the application until every job has been successfully completed.

You can read some notes on Spark's high availability [here](https://gist.github.com/aseigneurin/3af6b228490a8deab519c6aea2c209bc)

### Update:

As @user6910411 pointed out, there is a case in which you could lose data: if the data source being used by your Spark application is not persistent or it provides temporal data. In those cases the modification of the data used by the Spark application may lead to loss of data.

Comment: The whole statement is correct if and only if you make an assumption that the source of the data is persistent / reliable. If that's not the case executor failure can result in a unrecoverable data loss.

Comment: Agreed. If you have unreliable data source, its better you checkpoint i.e create a intermediate table from the source  and then process on it

Comment: You are both right, I have updated my answer pointing it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, no one of these cases relate to our, we read our data from files. Any other ideas which can lead to this strange behaviour?

Comment: @GregTk Sounds like you're dealing with a very specific scenario. Therefore question would really benefit with some form of [mcve] or at least a detailed description of the process (how you load, what `processData`, what it is the sink, how you log, and so on).